# How to save file with its original name in Struts2 while uploading a file

Tags: java, file, struts2

I need to save uploaded file with its original name and type instead of temporary file name in separate folder.

By using below code i can get file name and type but how can i change temporary name with its original name.

```
 private File file1;
 private String file1ContentType;
 private String file1FileName;

public File getFile1() {
 return file1;
}
public void setFile1(File file1) {
 this.file1 = file1;
}
public String getFile1ContentType() {
 return file1ContentType;
}
public void setFile1ContentType(String file1ContentType) {
 this.file1ContentType = file1ContentType;
}
public String getFile1FileName() {
 return file1FileName;
}
public void setFile1FileName(String file1FileName) {
 this.file1FileName = file1FileName;
}

public String upld() {      
    File dest = new File("/home/desktop/images/");
    try {

        System.out.println("file1FileName........"+file1FileName);
        System.out.println("file1ContentType........"+file1ContentType);
        System.out.println("file1........"+file1);

       FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(file1, dest);      
       } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
       }
       return "success";

    }
```

By this code its possible to save video with its temporary file name but i want to save file with its original name and type....

or else is it possible to rename temporary file with its original name before saving in to the folder

Comment: is it possible to change file name as according to our need while saving into folder?

Answer (score 0):

Turn

```
File dest = new File("/home/desktop/images/");
/*  ...  */
FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(file1, dest);
```

into

```
File dest = new File("/home/desktop/images/" + file1FileName);
/*  ...  */
FileUtils.copyFile(file1, dest);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

jsp code:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<html>
<head>
<s:head />
</head>

<body>
<h1>Struts 2 file upload example</h1>

<s:form action="resultAction" namespace="/" 
method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<s:file name="upload" label="Select a File to upload" size="40" />
User file :   <s:property value="uploadFileName"></s:property>
<s:submit value="submit" name="submit" />

</s:form>

</body>
</html>
```

Java Code:

```
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletRequestAware;



public class FileUploadAction extends ActionSupport implements ServletRequestAware {

    private File upload;

    public File getUpload() {
        return upload;
    }


    public void setUpload(File upload) {
        this.upload = upload;
    }


    public String getUploadDocContentType() {
        return uploadDocContentType;
    }


    public void setUploadDocContentType(String uploadDocContentType) {
        this.uploadDocContentType = uploadDocContentType;
    }


    private String uploadDocContentType;

    public HttpServletRequest request;
    public HttpSession session;
     public String uploadFileName;
    public String getUploadFileName() {
        return uploadFileName;
    }


    public void setUploadFileName(String uploadFileName) {
        this.uploadFileName = uploadFileName;
    }


    public String uploadImg() throws IOException{
        String targetPath ="/Desination path/";
        session = request.getSession(true);
        System.out.println("targetPath->"+uploadFileName);




        File fileToCreate = new File(targetPath, uploadFileName);
                try
                {
                        FileUtils.copyFile(this.upload, fileToCreate);
                }
                catch (IOException e) 
                {
                        addActionError(e.getMessage());
                }
                return "success";
    }


    @Override
    public void setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.request=request;

    }



}
```

Struts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>

      <constant name="struts.multipart.maxSize" value="20097152" />
      <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />

     <package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default ,json-default">
<action name="resultAction" class="FileUploadAction"  method="uploadImg">

        <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
            <param name="maximumSize">1024000</param>

            <param name="allowedTypes">image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg,image/pjpeg </param>
        </interceptor-ref>
         <interceptor-ref name="basicStack"/>
        <result name="success">/index.jsp</result>
        <result name="input">/index.jsp</result>
</action>
</package>
</struts>
```